# GLSL pow function?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl, fragment-shader

I have this:

```
    float xExponential = pow(xPingPong, 5);
```

And is not working, claiming:

> ERROR: 0:53: No matching overload for call to function 'pow'

Am I doin' something wrong?
Developing for iOS with OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
float xExponential = pow(xPingPong, 5.0);
```

Comment: Reason is that 5 is a integer and 5.0 is a float (and the pow function is not defined for pow(float,int). There is no automatically typecast in GLSL, but you could force the correct type by float xExponential = pow(xPingPong, float(5)); - not that it makes sense in this example.

Comment: @Geri It's considered polite to accept an answer if it helped you solve your problem. Hit the checkmark beside Mennan's answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine just syntax error

**Write upto decimal digit**

```
 float xExponential = pow(xPingPong, 5.0);
```

or

```
 float xExponential = pow(xPingPong, 5.);
```

Comment: the answer has already been given